# How to combine horizontal bar chars with line plots?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["A"] = [0.2, 0.4]
df["B"] = [0.3, 0.5]
df["C"] = [0.5, 0.1]
df["D"] = [2, 1]
df["Date"] = [dt.date(2022, 5, 31), dt.date(2022, 6, 30)]
```

I want to create barplots and add a line to this bar plot ("D" column).

Here is my solution:

```py
ax = df[["A", "B", "C", "Date"]].plot(kind="barh", stacked=True, x="Date")
df[["D", "Date"]].plot(
    x="Date", color="orange", use_index=False, secondary_y=True, ax=ax, marker="o"
)
```

The issues is that the "Date" axis is not picked properly (the right y-axis should be at the top and "Date" axis should be used for line plot instead of x-axis):

[image: Matplotlib Output]

How can I do that properly?